# How to include Helper into patch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, patch, redmine, redmine-plugins

Help me to include helper into patch because I need to use helper method in patched Controller method.
Commented code doesn`t working (
How to use it correct?

```
# helper :resources_user_list
# include ResourcesUserListHelper

module RedmineResourcesPlugin
  module Patches
    module RolesControllerPatch    
      def edit
        @role = Role.find_by_id(params[:id].to_i)
        @role_name = @role.name
        @role_members = @role.members
          .map(&:user).compact.uniq.find_all { |user| user.status == 1 }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require_dependency 'resources_user_list_helper'
```

Comment: thank you for  aswer but its doesnt working((((

"undefined local variable or method"

Comment: but meyby something wrong with method???


module ResourcesUserListHelper
  def roles_tabs
    tabs = []
    tabs << {:name => 'general', :partial => 'users_list/general', :label => :label_general}
    tabs << {:name => 'users', :partial => 'users_list/users', :label => :label_user_plural}
    tabs
  end
end

Comment: undefined local variable or method `roles_tabs' for #<#<Class:0x00000008254740>:0x007f9a61b117e8>

Comment: does this helper file/module belong to the same plugin? if yes, does it reside in `your_plugin/app/helpers` or `your_plugin/lib/your_plugin/helpers`?

Answer (score 0):

Put your helper in `app/helpers/resources_user_list_helper.rb` and the patch in `lib/redmine_resources_plugin/patches/roles_controller_patch.rb`. This way, you do not need to require anything since rails can autoload based on the class / module names.

Change your patch to look like this:

```rb
module RedmineResourcesPlugin
  module Patches
    module RolesControllerPatch
      def self.apply
        RolesController.prepend self
      end

      def self.prepended(base)
        base.class_eval do
          helper :resources_user_list
        end
      end

      def edit
        @role = Role.find_by_id(params[:id].to_i)
        @role_name = @role.name
        @role_members = @role.members
          .map(&:user).compact.uniq.find_all { |user| user.status == 1 }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

in init.rb:

```rb
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  RedmineResourcesPlugin::Patches::RolesControllerPatch.apply
end
```

While the `apply` part is optional and you can call prepend in init.rb, I prefer it this way since it makes init.rb much more readable.

Regarding your patch - `@role` should already be initialized when the `edit` method is entered due to a `before_action` - there is no need to find it again.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I`he done this like this :

`require_dependency 'resources_user_list_helper'`

but I need to put this in the file
`redmine_resources/init.rb`

Thank you!